# Exact sequence induced by associate prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring such that $\mathfrak{m} \in \operatorname{Ass}(A)$. How can we get the injective map $ A/\mathfrak{m} \to A$? For example, if $\overline{a}=\overline{a'}$ for some $a,a' \in A \setminus \mathfrak{m}$, then $a=a'+m$ for some $m \in \mathfrak{m}$, thus it seems that there are no way to generate a canonical embedding.

This claim is came from Matsumura's Commutative Ring Theory, Section 18, p.142. The author assumes that injective dimension of $A$ is finite, but I think it is not relevant for getting this injective map.

Comment: What is the definition of associated prime that you use?

Comment: Who said that the embedding is "canonical"? We know that m=ann(a), so A/m=A/ann(a) which is isomorphic as **A-module** with Aa which is an ideal, hence a submodule of A.

Comment: @user26857 Oh that's my bad; I thought the injective map is came from canonical embedding. Thank you very much, as always!